# 503, Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: http-status-code-503

Sometimes the following error appears:

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I reformatted your question to make it easier to read. Please [edit] it and add some detail about what you are trying to do. What web server are you using? What programming language? These should also be added as tags.

Comment: I am recently facing this error on PHP Website hosted on a Bluehost server. Did you manage to resolve this error? I called support, and they say it's something to do with the server after a few days it was OK, but then later the error returns. I somehow don't trust what support says.